# Comparing multiple variables for equality in Bash

Tags: bash

I want to test that multiple files have the same number of lines from a bash script.

I have a few variables, each of which stores the number of lines in a given file.

To check that the files each have the same number of lines I have the following check:

```
if [ $lines_in_dev4 -ne $lines_in_dev5 ] || [ $lines_in_dev4 -ne $lines_in_uat ] || [ $lines_in_dev4 -ne $lines_in_test ]; then
    echo "A new property hasn't been added to all files"
    exit 1
fi
```

This works but feels verbose - is there a way to chain the comparisons, or some common utility I can pass all the variables to and get back a yes/no as to whether all the variables are equal or not?

Comment: `eq(){ [ $(echo $* | fmt -1 | uniq | wc -l) = 1 ]; }; eq 1 2 3 && echo yes || echo no`

Comment: There si nothing wrong with your comparison and it isn't "verbose", but you do need to quote all variables used within `[ .. ]` -- unlike within `[[ .. ]]`.

Comment: @tschumann : If you have that many variables that you are wondering about this problem, I wonder why you don't use an array instead.

Answer (score 3):

For a function that takes the line counts as arguments and prints how many different ones there are, you could use a function like this:

```
uniquevals() {
    local c counts
    for c; do
        counts[c]=1
    done

    echo "${#counts[@]}"
}
```

The array `counts` gets a new element for each unique positional parameter, and because Bash arrays are sparse, we can count the number of elements with `${#counts[@]}`.

Usage examples:

```
$ uniquevals 1 2 100
3
$ uniquevals 1 2 2
2
$ uniquevals 1 1 1
1
```

If you wanted to be able to supply filenames instead of the line counts, you could modify like this:

```
uniquelcounts() {
    local f counts
    for f; do
        counts[$(wc -l < "$f")]=1
    done

    echo "${#counts[@]}"
}
```

used like

```
$ uniquelcounts file1 file1 file2
2
```

assuming that `file1` and `file2` don't have the same number of lines.

And finally, to use that to check if all are equal:

```
allequal() {
    local c counts
    for c; do
        counts[c]=1
    done

    if ((${#counts[@]} > 1)); then
        return 1
    fi
    return 0
}
```

used like

```
$ if allequal 1 1; then echo yes; else echo no; fi
yes
$ if allequal 1 2; then echo yes; else echo no; fi
no
```

Answer (score 1):

> is there a way to chain the comparisons

Built directly into bash? Not that I would know.

> or some common utility I can pass all the variables to and get back a yes/no

I think the closest thing to such a command would be `sort | uniq` or just `sort -u`. You only have to make sure that the output contains exactly one line. All of the following functions exit with status 0 in case all variables are equal and with status 1 if some variables differ from each other.

```
allEqual() {
    [ 1 = "$(printf %s\\n "$@" | sort -u | wc -l)" ]
}
```

The function assumes that all variables contain at most one line of text. With `sort` implementations like GNU sort you can even compare multi-line strings:

```
allEqual() {
    [ 1 = "$(printf %s\\0 "$@" | sort -uz | tr -cd \\0 | wc -c)" ]
}
```

Define the function as shown above and then use it as follows:

```
allEqual "$var1" "$var2" "$var3" …
```

## Simplified Call

With bash's indirection operator you can even write a function which takes only the variable names. That way you don't have to expand and quote the variables manually:

```
allVarEqual() {
    first="${!1}"
    shift
    for name in "$@"; do
        [ "${!name}" = "$first" ] || return 1
    done
}
```

Use this function as follows:

```
allVarEqual var1 var2 var3
```

## Simplified Function For Your Use Case

> I want to test that multiple files have the same number of lines

Considering this you don't need the variables at all. You can directly compare that all files have the same number of lines:

```
filesHaveSameLength() {
    [ "$#" -lt 2 ] && return 0
    [ 1 = "$(wc -l "$@" | head -n-1 | awk '{print $1}' | sort -u | wc -l)" ] 
}
```

```
filesHaveSameLength file1 file2 file3 ...
```